# Error while installing ipython[notebook]

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to install ipython[notebook] and I am getting this error while installing ipython[notebook] using the command
Python -m pip install ipython[notebook].

I updated setup already using python -m pip update setup.

```
writing MarkupSafe.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MarkupSafe.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MarkupSafe.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
copying markupsafe\_speedups.c -> build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
running build_ext
building 'markupsafe._speedups' extension
error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

---------------------------------------
```

I even tried installing Markup Safe using the command python-m pip install markup safe which failed giving the error:

```
writing MarkupSafe.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MarkupSafe.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MarkupSafe.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
copying markupsafe\_speedups.c -> build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
running build_ext
building 'markupsafe._speedups' extension
error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

---

Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\

Installing Mark up safe speedups is giving this error:
C:\Python27>python -m pip install markupsafe._speedups
Collecting markupsafe._speedupsCould not find a version that satisfies the requirement markupsafe._speedups (from versions: )No matching distribution found for markupsafe._speedups

Comment: Just install Anaconda directly, it's way easyer for Windows users https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: I have compatability issues running Anaconda.

Comment: +1 for anaconda. but if you want to stick to just regular python 2.7, you may need to install the toolchain for c extensions to play nicely. get it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266 (the _speedups module is a c-extension)

Comment: I could successfully install ipython[notebook] after installing toolchain for c extensions.Thank you.